# Optimise startup animation

Tags: objective-c, image, animation, optimization

I am trying to do a startup animation but this is using a lot of space. Making my app 50mb in size and causing a huge shot in the memory which hits 288mb and stays there when running the app.

So the animation consists of 90 images like this:

```
-(UIImageView *) InitImageView{
    CGRect  rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
    UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00000.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00001.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00002.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00003.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00004.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00005.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00006.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00007.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00008.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00009.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00010.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00011.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00012.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00013.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00014.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00015.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00016.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00017.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00018.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00019.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00020.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00021.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00022.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00023.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00024.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00025.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00026.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00027.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00028.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00029.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00030.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00031.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00032.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00033.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00034.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00035.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00036.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00037.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00038.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00039.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00040.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00041.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00042.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00043.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00044.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00045.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00046.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00047.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00048.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00049.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00050.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00051.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00052.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00053.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00054.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00055.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00056.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00057.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00058.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00059.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00060.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00061.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00062.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00063.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00064.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00065.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00066.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00067.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00068.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00069.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00070.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00071.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00072.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00073.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00074.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00075.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00076.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00077.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00078.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00079.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00080.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00081.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00082.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00083.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00084.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00085.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00086.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00087.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00088.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00089.png"], nil];
    //imageView.animationDuration = 6;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    return imageView;
}
```

Each image has a 640px by 1136px by display dimension. At a resolution of 72 pixels/inch.

What methods could I use to optimise this startup animation to work with the iPhone 4, 5 and 6/6+ ?

For example:

- Change image dimension to...
- Change image resolution to...

Comment: Why don't you replace all of the images with a precompiled video to play at startup instead?

Comment: What's killing you here is loading all 90 images into an array. Bad idea. The first thing I would try is, use an animated image, where all you have to do is give the name of one image and it finds all the rest. - But if that doesn't work, then just don't do that. Use a real animation (or, as @JosueEspinosa says, make a video).

Comment: @JosueEspinosa because the animation turns into the background of the actual application

Comment: 50mb is pretty small for a video sequence at 640x1136 (close to HD!)

Comment: I don't understand why you would be unable to use a video? The effect would be the same except you don't have to make 90 separate images. The last frame would be the same as the last image. If you must, play the video, then add the very last image, which will have the same effect as what you are currently doing.

Comment: Yes but a sudden loss of quality might occur? Also how large will the video have to be?

Comment: @Maximilian you will have to play with the video encoding a little but trust me, it works perfectly fine that way and it will not be recognizable if you tune the settings accordingly. I've done this exact thing in the past.

Comment: Okay @Till what dimensions, format etc... Should I set the video to have it at an optimal screen resolution? For all devices